# How to fix the default compilesdk version?

Tags: android-studio

I want to know how to fix my compilesdk version to 33 in build.gradle(:app) file.

Whenever I create a project, I have to go to the gradle file and change the sdk version from 32 to 33.

this is so annoying routine for me.

Anybody know about this issue, please help me :<

-- I have attached some setting image

[sdk manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XW0H1.jpg)

I unchecked Android SDK Platform 32. but when I create new project, 32 is automatically downloaded.

What did I try

1. Uncheck the other version in sdk manager window
2. Then create new project, unchecked version 32 is automatically downloaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Whenever I create a project, I have to go to the gradle file and change the sdk version from 32 to 33.

The SDK version 32 is automatically added by the project template generator in Android Studio. It is usually increased after some time but not frequently. Its something you gotta learn to live with because not all developers prefer the newest SDK Version.

> I unchecked Android SDK Platform 32. but when I create new project, 32 is automatically downloaded.

This happens automatically because of the reason above,you dont have to fight it.It is also a one time occurence.The IDE downloads the SDK source files only once. If you change the compile SDK to 33, it proceeds to download the source files for that version.

Comment: thank you for detailed explanation. I gotta downgrade my SDK version to 32 and use it.